# Monitor for Resource: BigQuery Dataset, Metric: Uploaded rows is not realtime

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

It takes several hours for data to show up on the chart. This is the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the official documentation[1] "there are some Bigquery metrics that the time is delayed up to several hours". This delay is on the BigQuery side; Bigquery has a pipeline that computes the metrics asynchronously and it can take several hours to run. Also, some BigQuery metrics are delayed by 6 hours while others are delayed by 2 hours.
[1]https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/monitoring#metrics